# Append a User Defined Function's output to a existing vector without printing the output in R

Tags: r, function, vector, append

Suppose I have a blank vector -

```
ot_vec = c()
```

Now I have many user-defined functions e.g. `Square_Calculator`, `SquareRoot_Calculator` etc as defined below -

```
square_calculator <- function(x){
  sq = x*x
  sq
}
```

```
squareRoot_calculator <- function(x){
  sq_rt = sqrt(x)
  sq_rt
}
```

Now I want a code that will append the outputs of these functions one by one to the existing blank vector `ot_vec` w/o printing the outputs. Like the below -

After running these three lines of code -

```
square_calculator(2)
squareRoot_calculator(100)
square_calculator(5)
```

The Null Vector `ot_vec` should give output as  -

[image: Output]

**Note:**
I don't need anything like - `ot_vec = c(ot_vec, Square_Calculator(2), SquareRoot_Calculator(100), Square_Calculator(5))` i.e., **I want to modify the user-defined functions in a way that they instead of giving output, directly they will append output to the null vector.**

I was trying something like -

[image: My Try]

Comment: You *could* mutate `ot_vec` from inside the function with `<<-` or `assign` - which doesn't mean you *should* ;-)

Comment: @I_O They definitely *shouldn't*.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to provide a bit more context about why you want to do this. The answers posted will achieve what you ask for but they will lead to convoluted code and increase the chance of bugs. There may be a better way to achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: @SamR This is the main question i am asking for -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058378/using-trycatch-append-output-of-user-defined-functions-to-a-list-and-warnings-er

It is mainly intended for running the defined functions and collecting their status at the end of the entire code

Answer (score 2):

Maybe environments are what you are looking for. But the variable to be changed must be passed to the functions changing it.

```r
square_calculator <- function(x, y, envir = parent.frame()){
  sq = x*x
  yname <- as.character(substitute(y))
  envir[[yname]] <- c(envir[[yname]], sq)
}
squareRoot_calculator <- function(x, y, envir = parent.frame()){
  sq_rt = sqrt(x)
  yname <- as.character(substitute(y))
  envir[[yname]] <- c(envir[[yname]], sq_rt)
}

ot_vec <- NULL
square_calculator(2, ot_vec)
squareRoot_calculator(100, ot_vec)
square_calculator(5, ot_vec)
ot_vec
#> [1]  4 10 25
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign to a variable in the parent frame. That is to assign a value to a name. One solution would be to call the modified `square_calculator` with the name of the variable:

```r
ot_vec <- c()

square_calculator <- function(x, vec) {
  sq <- x*x
  assign(vec,
         c(get(vec), sq),
         env = parent.frame())
}
```

```r
square_calculator(10, "ot_vec")
> ot_vec
[1] 100
```